# In the payment controller, how do I get the quote/order ID that the user checked out?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, payment-methods

The payment method I have uses a third party gateway. I need to forward the Increment Order ID to them.

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
    return Mage::getUrl('shopping/checkout/forwardweb', array('_secure' => true));
}
```

What I would like to do is to get the order and send the `$order->getIncrementId()`.

I tried using `$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();`

But for some reason, it's always returning the same order id, no matter how many times I check out my cart, and if I go to the website, and list the orders, the new orders are not being added to the list, and it's always empty.

Comment: Have you check at table sales_flat_order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last order increment id by

```
$last_order_increment_id = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();
```

**You will need to save reserveOrderId in quote.**

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::reserveOrderId()
```

Paypal express method doing the same in function

```
Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::start()
```

You can follow the way it is doing and send your increment id same way for your payment method.

Comment: But how do I get the ID of the order that was created by the checkout page for that customer, rather than just the last order id?

Comment: edited my answer.